# Is the statement that LN hot wallets will be less secure than non LN hot wallets correct?

Tags: security, lightning-network

I say this because of the following reasoning: Lightning network wallets will have to completely possess my private key, whereas non-LN hot wallets will most of the time only have my key encrypted (I sign the tx locally over my browser).

Answer (score 1):

Of course this depends a lot on the implementation you are using but generally the answer is *yes*.

```
LN wallet vulnerabilites = hot wallet vulnerabilities + LN protocol vulnerabilites
```

Here are the main additional issues coming with running a LN node:

- You could be scammed by somebody releasing an old channel state
- You announce to the whole world how much money you have on your node [this is optional and depends on whether you want your node to be routing other peoples payments or not]